# how to create a network of instances of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, networking, instance

I have a simple class an instance of which can accept an input value and provide an output value. I want to create a network of instances of this class, with outputs of some instances linked to inputs of other instances. Is there a class or some other way of defining such a network in a clear, efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to implement a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph). There are many ways to implement a graph I recommend you to read [Python Patterns - Implementing Graphs](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/).

A simple idea:  You could hold a list of every instance you want to pass input to (that's also a graph).

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.targets = []

    def output(self):
        for target in self.targets:
            target.process_input(self.produce_output())


    def process_input(self, input):
        # Process some data here.
        pass


    def produce_output():
        # Produce some data here.
        pass
```